# Are there any good references regarding non-learnability in statistical learning theory?

Tags: machine-learning, references

For example, I don't see a lot come up in my search for "non-learnability" ... is there another term? Specifically I'm imagining that similar to the Learning Guarantees from statistical learning theory there might be some results concerning non-learnability guarantees. Or are these equivalent in some simple way that I am not seeing?

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397512009358